# How to call .hover from Template.<template>.events api in coffeescript

Tags: jquery, meteor, coffeescript

How do you register the two required functions for .hover when using meteor's Template..events api in coffeescript?

I'm trying something along the lines of:

```
Template.<template>.events
  'hover #elementID': (
     (ev) -> console.log 'hello world'
     (ev) -> console.log 'bye world'
   )
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Saimeunt's is correct, but if you want it to be exactly as .hover() jquery uses mouseenter and mouseleave instead. So it'd be:

```js
Template.<template>.events
  "mouseenter #elementID": (event, template) ->
    console.log "mousehover", event
  "mouseleave #elementID": (event, template) ->
    console.log "mouseout", event
```

Comment: I was looking to see if it's possible to directly call .hover within the template events as one normally can without meteor, but considering all of my attempts and what I'm finding here, it seems this is not possible and you have to directly use the mouseenter and mouseleave events.  Upvote for this anyway.

Comment: The only accepted event types are: click, dblclick, focus, blur, change, mouseenter, mouseleave, mousedown, mouseup, keydown, keypress and keyup. So we're missing a few, but nothing we can't get around ;)

Comment: this is useful reference for those not using coffeescript also. Thanks nick.

Answer (score 6):

The correct syntax is something like :

```
Template.myTemplate.events
  "mouseover #elementID": (event, template) ->
    console.log "mousehover", event
  "mouseout #elementID": (event, template) ->
    console.log "mouseout", event
```